# customizing part style

Tags: parts

I'm trying to custom my part style, how could I customize it like below picture?[image]

Comment: What is the graphic part? Some barcode?

Comment: First, figure out how to generate the desired page (I would use tikz). Second, figure out how to get \part to use your format. Basically this means replacing \@part (see base.sty), or at least parts of it.  There is also \@spart which probably handles \part*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an approach with `report` class, as mentioned by @JohnKormylo the better is replacing `\@part` but i expect the code below enough in your case.

The command `\topleft` indicate the distance of vertical lines from left edge of paper you can change it as you like.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother  

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\def\topleft{4}

\newcommand{\cpart}[1]{
\clearpage
\stepcounter{part}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\coordinate(ptopleft) at ($(current page.north west)+(\topleft,0)$);
\foreach \i in{0,.1,.2,.3,.5,.6,.9,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.6,1.8,1.9,2}
\draw[gray!70]($(ptopleft)+(\i,0)$)--+(0,-\paperheight);
\node[white,fill=black,minimum size=1.5cm](A) at ($(ptopleft)+(1,-2)$){\huge\thepart};
\node [anchor=south,ultra thick,yshift=-1mm]at(A.north){\Large PART};
\node [fill=white,anchor=north,very thick,right=-2mm,inner sep=5mm]at($(ptopleft)+(0,-0.5\paperheight)$){\Huge #1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
}
\begin{document}‎‎‎

\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cpart{Part title title title}
\chapter{chapter one}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{chapter two}
\lipsum[1-3]
‎\end{document}‎
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Very nice! Is it possible to include the design with \titleformat{\part}[display]?